# How do I make a portable program with OpenCV2 on C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, camera, portability

I have installed OpenCV on Windows 10 and using C++ in Visual Studio.

Now I'm trying to make a program that makes several photos then saves them.

Problem:

I made a copy of project on USB flash (go to another PC) and when I try to start it from .exe file, I get this error: [image: Error on other PC]

How can start it without installing 1Gb of FULL OpenCV libraries?

I tried to start from release version.

My C++ source:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h> // For Sleep

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


int main(int, char**)
{
    VideoCapture cap(0);

    // Get the frame
    Mat save_img; cap >> save_img;

    if (save_img.empty())
    {
        std::cerr << "Something is wrong with the webcam, could not get frame." << std::endl;
    }
    // Save the frame into a file
    imwrite("test.jpg", save_img); // A JPG FILE IS BEING SAVED
    return 0;
}
```

My settings:
[image]
[image]
[image]

P.S. I want to make light program for making photo on Windows.  And how to make real portable programs.

Comment: get an opencv build with individual libraries, not the one big "world" dll. then distribute the dlls you need.